# Jiffy difference in month

Tags: flutter, dart

I use `Jiffy` for calculate the difference in between 2 date in month.
But I don't the good result.

For end = 2/4/2023 and start = 1/4/2022 I have 12 months.

For end = 1/4/2023 and start = 1/4/2022 I have 11 months (error: expected 12).

Thanks,

```
num month = Jiffy(end).diff(Jiffy(start), Units.MONTH);
```

Comment: Hey you can add 1 day to end date

Comment: Yes but I would like to understand the behavior. Because by changing the day possibly I could have the opposite problem.

Comment: Did you try to convert date to UTC and then compare because that might be due to day light hours

Comment: The convert in UTC have the same problem.

Comment: Date arithmetic is hard, and often misunderstood.  And DST makes it worse (let's abolish DST please!).

Comment: Shouldn't you have expected 13 months for the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is checking 12 at midnight to 12 at midnight of the end date which is 11 months 30 days. Now if the end date is one second greater than the correct date it should work. So a hackey solution is to add one day duration to the end date and check

```
end.add(duration(day:1))
```

Comment: Thank, I understand the behavior of `Jiffy.diff`